# Convert multiple text files into csv then save each lines into a new files with unique names

Tags: excel, text, merge, converters, extract

I have a massive headache and I need some help.I have little to know knowledge on this, but I think I know what I need the program to do.

Here is what I have:
multiple folders named with numbers (1, 2, 3, ...). Inside each folder is a file called "PData.dat".

PData.dat contains this text

```
[PatData]
InternalID=1090
ID=1
IsActive=1 (1=True, 0=False)
IsPatient=1
IsRP=0
Title=
FirstName=John
MidName=
LastName=Smith
```

What I need:
I need to put this data in an excel file

```
PatientID    IsActive   IsPatient   IsRP    Title   FirstName   MidName LastName<br>
'###         True        True        False           John                Smith
```

Then
Extract each line from excel back into a file with the "PatientID" as the folder name and the original "Pdata.dat" inside that folder.

Comment: I think you would want to use VBA for this.

Comment: Formatting your sample "file" as code, using the curly braces in the edit box, makes it easier to see the columns.